# The Entire Array

Tags: php, arrays, email

So I am making a little Mail form for practice, anyways.

I want to make a array of emails that cant be emailed to,

```
$nomail = array("hego556@yahoo.com","firevm@yahoo.com");
if($_POST["to"]!=$nomail)
  mail($_POST["to"],$_POST["subject"],$_POST["message"],$headers);
else
  echo "Not Allowed To Email That Email";
```

How do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `in_array`.

```
if (!in_array($_POST["to"], $nomail)) {
```

https://www.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `if($_POST["to"]!=$nomail)` to `if (in_array($_POST['to'], $noemail))`

[Relevant](http://php.net/in_array)

Answer (score 1):

```
$nomail = array('hego556@yahoo.com', 'firevm@yahoo.com');

if (!in_array($_POST['to'], $nomail)) {
    mail($_POST["to"],$_POST["subject"],$_POST["message"],$headers);
} else {
    echo 'Not Allowed To Email That Email';
}
```